# Emails from MailApp.sendEmail always go to junk

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I created a script to run some task from the Spreadsheet and it will send a emails using `MailApp.sendEmail` if the conditions are right. I found that all the emails sent to me are all put into junk.

The recipient is `@live.com` from Outlook.com service. The sender and receiver is the same email address, my own email address. I tried filtering things on Outlook.com and it doesn't help.

This problem somehow should be solved by recipient's service. But when the script is used for multiple receivers that I cannot control them all. There is something that must be done from the sender's part.

---

Here is my example function to send the email. Edited following @amit-agarwal's suggestion. Still not solved:

```
function sendEmail(lastvalue, newvalue, lastdate, newdate) {
  var content = 'New value detected\n'
  + 'This time (' +  newdate + ') :\n' +  newvalue.toFixed(3) + '\n\n'
  + 'Last time (' + lastdate + ') :\n' + lastvalue.toFixed(3);
  
  MailApp.sendEmail(mailRecipients.join(), 'New value detected', content);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is likely related to the email message body.

Consider sending the email in plain text if you are using HTML. Also ensure that email doesn't contain any links or files that may be seen as suspicious.

Comment: Thank you @amit-agarwal. I tried changing my function following your suggestion but it doesn't help. I added the edited code into the original post above.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution?